# Tipo de parâmetro inválido ao utilizar CURL com PHP

Tags: php, libcurl

Bom pessoal faço uma requisição na API do pagar.me para eu recuperar alguns dados do cartão de crédito.
Quando eu utilizo diretamente pelo terminal com esse código, recebo o JSON corretamente com todos os dados pedidos:

```
curl -X GET https://api.pagar.me/1/transactions/ID_transacao -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
     "api_key": "CHAVE_API"
 }'
```

Mas quando tento passar para o php não sei o que estou fazendo errado, pois recebo o seguinte erro que meus parâmetros estão incorretos do pagar.me

```
{"errors":[{"type":"invalid_parameter","parameter_name":"api_key","message":"api_key está faltando"}],"url":"/transactions/ID_transacao","method":"get"}
```

Meu código em PHP está da seguinte forma:

```
$date = array(
    "api_key" => "CHAVE_API"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.pagar.me/1/transactions/ID_transacao");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 'content-type: application/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $date);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

Qual seria a forma correta passar esse parâmetro?

Link da API do pagar.me: https://docs.pagar.me/reference

OBS: tenho que usar o curl para fazer essa requisição, não posso utilizar API deles para Php.

Comment: Parece-me que o problema é essa configuração "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');", mas api_key é enviada por POST, dá uma olhada na documentação em https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do Pagar.ME, a requisição deste tipo seria por GET (Retornando uma transação), conforme está descrito neste link:

[https://docs.pagar.me/reference#retornando-um-transação](https://docs.pagar.me/reference#retornando-um-transa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Tente fazer a chamada da seguinte forma:

```html
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.pagar.me/1/transactions/1835855');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n    \"api_key\": \"SUA_API_KEY\"\n}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo! estava com dificuldade em montar o POSTFIELD